# Using the jQuery Validation plugin is there a way of using 2 regex patterns for the same input field?

Tags: jquery

In my HTML, I have a field which has two format checks, each with a different error message. I am using the pattern field with regex in each case. But of course, having two fields of the same name in the same object is a no-no and jQuery Validation just ignores the first one.

```
 {% include "includes/jquery_validation.njk" %}
    {% include "includes/client_side_form_validation_config.njk" %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          $('#tpas_phonenumber_form')
             .submit(function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
                var rules = {
                    onfocusout: false,
                    onkeyup: false,
                    rules: {
                        txt_tpas_phonenumber: {
                            required: true,
                            pattern: /^((07|7)\d{3}?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/,
                            pattern: /^(\+?\d{1,10}|d{2,11})$/
                        }
                     },
                     messages: {
                        txt_tpas_phonenumber: {
                            required: "{{ __('signup_set_phonenumber_error_phonenumber_required') }}",
                            pattern: "{{ __('signup_set_phonenumber_error_enter_a_UK_mobile') }}",
                            pattern: "{{ __('signup_set_phonenumber_error_incorrect_format') }}"
                        }
                    }
                };

                $('#tpas_phonenumber_form').validate(rules);
                if ($('#tpas_phonenumber_form').valid()) {
                  // Form is valid, now populate B2C fields and submit the form
                  $('#phoneNumber').val($('#txt_tpas_phonenumber').val());
                  $('#continue').click();
                }
              })
        });
```

Is there an elegant solution to my problem, or will I have write a new routine that doesn't use jQuery Validator?

Comment: How is it supposed to use both patterns? Does it have to match both of them or either of them?

Comment: If it can be either, just make it a single patter with alternatives: `pattern: /(pattern1)|(pattern2)/`

Comment: In your second pattern, is `d{2,11}` supposed to be `\d{2,11}`?

Comment: The first regex (which may not be correct) tests that the phone number is for a UK mobile (i.e. starts with 07, 044 or +44). The second one checks that the number has the correct number of digits. The error messages for those 2 conditions are different. 

I've not yet tested the regexes properly yet so they're almost certainly wrong but that's a problem for another day.

Comment: The second pattern allows the number to start with an optional `+`, but the first pattern doesn't. And the first pattern allows optional spaces, but the second doesn't. So if the user enters any of these optional characters, it won't match both patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two regular expressions using a lookahead to validate the length. However, you can't produce different error messages depending on which part of the pattern you fail to match, so you'll have to change the error message to encompass both problems.

```
                    onfocusout: false,
                    onkeyup: false,
                    rules: {
                        txt_tpas_phonenumber: {
                            required: true,
                            pattern: /^(?=(\+?\d{1,10}|\d{2,11})$)(07|7)\d{3}?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/,
                        }
                     },
                     messages: {
                        txt_tpas_phonenumber: {
                            required: "{{ __('signup_set_phonenumber_error_phonenumber_required') }}",
                            pattern: "{{ __('signup_set_phonenumber_error_enter_a_UK_mobile') }}",
                        }
                    }
                };
```